# jquery, undefined variable problem, how to?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have this situation:

```
<div class="cont_picture">
<?php echo "<a id=\"mine_click\" href=\"#\" >a test</a>"; ?>
</div>
<div id="number"><?php echo $number; ?></div>
```

this will give me something like: [a test](http://www.google.com) 123456   (*the link is as an example only*)

then i have the jquery:

```
$('#mine_click').live('click', function() {
    var strtalentnum = $('#number').text();
    $('#mine').trigger('click');
})
```

and;

```
if($strtalentnum){
alert ($strtalentnum);
}
```

but the alert doesnt work.

Any ideas how to get this working?  see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrNtK/)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `strtalentnum` inside `#mine_click` `click` event handler and try to access it outside the handler which is out of scope. If you want to access it outside the handler then define it in the outer scope or glbally.

Also the variable you are trying to alert begins with `$`. I think its a typo.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrNtK/15/)**

```
var strtalentnum;

$('#mine_click').live('click', function() {
    strtalentnum = $('#number').text();
    $('#mine').trigger('click');
});

$('#mine').click(function(){
   if(strtalentnum){
       alert (strtalentnum);
   }
});
```

Comment: this will never trigger the alert, because when the if executes, it will always be `undefined`

Comment: @Shank do you not see the first comment? down voted because your original example didn't work, vengeful down voting is not very nice either...

Comment: I didnt provide any example in my original answer. I added the demo later after editing. Aslo can you tell me anywhere mentioned in the question where is `if($strtalentnum){
alert ($strtalentnum);
}` executed? I believe it is inside `$('#mine').click` handler.

Comment: it's not... but that's the problem that caused him to post the question... he wan'ts it to...  if you don't think he ever wants to execute it why did you edit your answer to do so?

Comment: Looking at `$('#mine').trigger('click');` in the click handler made me do so.

Comment: right, so "looking at the question again" you agree with me that his intention was to execute the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `if` inside the function() and beware that you are writing `$strtalentnum` but the variable is called `strtalentnum`